# Preg replace, doesn't replace any div tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove, two div tags from my code.

I'm using `preg_replace` to do that(Was my one thought). I've also tried to do `str_replace`, but that isn't so optimal(didn't work also, lol.)

Here is what i'm doing:

```
$trimmed_content = addslashes(trim($_POST[custom_doc])); #Adding slashes
$strreplace = preg_replace('/<div data-doc=customized"><div class="customized">(.*?)<\/div><\/div>/', '$1', $trimmed_content); #Replacing tags
```

So at line one, I'm adding slashes to the `$_POST` value, and then trimming the space, at the front, and at the back.
After that, I'm trying to replace the data doc and class.

But the problem is, that it STILLS take both the data-doc, and the class with it.

I feel like I tried everything, and now I want to rip the hair out of my skull.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: It's quite hard to manipulate HTML with regular expressions. Do you have the option of using a proper DOM parser?

Comment: So you add slashes to all quotes and then you try to use a regex to match your - by now invalid - html using un-escaped quotes. Forgetting one quote in the process as well. You should really reconsider this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/42139

Comment: Use preg_quote instead of addslashes.

Comment: Is it a typo or quote is missing in `data-doc=customized">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$value = '<div data-doc="customized"><div class="customized">sometext</div></div>';
$trimmed_content = addslashes(trim($value)); #Adding slashes
$strreplace = preg_replace('/<.*"customized.">(.*)(<\/div>.*){2}/s', "$1", $trimmed_content); #Replacing tags
```

Comment: Can you give an example from the $_POST input?

Comment: It stumbles over the whitespaces and line breaks / new lines (\r\n).

Comment: I have added the /s Flag for single line. Now . matches new line too.